# Couple of classical Japanese questions

Tags: classical-japanese, poetry

I found a poem by Nagai Kafu entitled 震災 (The Earthquake) in a volume of Japanese prose and poetry. It's a short poem about the Ansei Edo Earthquake (安政江戸地震) in 1855 which destroyed the red light district Yoshiwara. I reproduce the parts of the poem which I have some questions about:

> 今の世の若き人々
>
> われにな問いにそ今の世と
>
> また来る時代の藝術を

What is the structure of われにな問いにそ? I understand it's construed as a negative imperative ("Do not ask me ...") but I don't recognise the syntax.

> われは明治の兒ならずや

I understand that -ならず is the 未然形 of なり, but what is the correct translation of ならず + や?

> わが感激の泉とくに枯れたり

Is there an adverb とくに in this line, or am I parsing it incorrectly?

Comment: Isn't it われにな問いそ? な問い**に**そ sounds unnatural in this passage.

Comment: If it's really 問いにそ, we can probably interpret the に as 連用形 of  完了ぬ for emphasis.

Comment: @user4092 ぬ's "emphasis" indicates expectancy of realization, which seems to contradict the prohibition, I think. But maybe my imagination, since I'm not a native Classical Japanese speaker...

Comment: I'm not native in that aspect either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://mokuou.blogspot.jp/2010/11/blog-post_16.html) seems to show what the original poem is like.

> われに**な問ひそ**今の世と

The original text goes like this. The `な V そ` sandwich (`V` takes 連用形 except for す and 来 become 未然形, せ and こ) is a common Classical pattern for negative imperative "please don't", which is given [a detailed explanation](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D) in Japanese dictionary.

> われは明治の兒ならずや

`negative` + 係助詞 [`や`](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84) (no particular order) are combined to be rhetorical question. So here it says "Am I not a child of Meiji (times)?", or in this context, "Know you not, I am a child of Meiji?"

> わが感激の泉とくに枯れたり

There is an adverb とくに, means "[already](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/158236/m0u/)"; not the one means "[especially](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/158236/m0u/)".

Answer (score 2):

I offer my translation, made thanks to the community.

*Note:* the names mentioned by the poet Nagai -- Dangiku, Ochi, Ichiyo, Koyo, Ryokuu, Encho, Shicho, Ryuson and Ogai Gyoshi -- were all contemporary poets, performers and figures of the Meiji period.

For some of them, Nagai describes their falling into oblivion punningly, in a manner befitting their names.

> 今の世の若き人々
>
> Young people of our age,
>
> われにな問ひそ今の世と
>
> ask me not of the arts of our age and
>
> また来る時代の藝術を。
>
> those of the age to come.
>
> われは明治の兒ならずや。
>
> Am I not a child of the Meiji?
>
> その文化歴史となりて葬られし時
>
> When that culture and its history were entombed
>
> わが青春の夢もまた消えにけり。
>
> The dreams of my youth, too, disappeared.
>
> 團菊はしをれて桜癡は散りにき。
>
> Dangiku dried up, and Ochi dispersed.
>
> 一葉落ちて紅葉は枯れ
>
> Ichiyo fell, Koyo withered,
>
> 緑雨の聲も亦絶えたりき。
>
> Ryokuu's voice too was severed.
>
> 圓朝も去れり紫蝶も去れり。
>
> Encho passed, Shicho too.
>
> わが感激の泉とくに枯れたり。
>
> My wellspring of emotion too, already withered.
>
> われは明治の兒なりけり。
>
> I was a child of the Meiji.
>
> 或年大地俄にゆらめき
>
> One year, the earth shook, and
>
> 火は都を燬きぬ。
>
> Fire destroyed the capital.
>
> 柳村先生既になく
>
> Master Ryuuson was already gone;
>
> 鴎外漁史も亦姿をかくしぬ。
>
> Ougai Gyoshi too, vanished from our sight.
>
> 江戸文化の名残烟となりぬ。
>
> Edo, the remnants of its culture, became as smoke.
>
> 明治の文化また灰となりぬ。
>
> Meiji, its culture too, became as ash.
>
> 今の世のわかき人々
>
> Young people of our age,
>
> 我にな語りそ今の世と
>
> speak not to me of the arts of our age and
>
> また来む時代の藝術を。
>
> the age which be to come.
>
> くもりし眼鏡ふくとても
>
> Now though I wipe my clouded glasses,
>
> われ今何をか見得べき。
>
> what is there to see?
>
> われは明治の兒ならずや。
>
> Am I not a child of the Meiji?
>
> 去りし明治の世の兒ならずや。
>
> Not a child of the Meiji age, long-gone?

Comment: Nice work, though I see old and new kanji jumbled together. Is this how it appears in your source text?

Comment: My source actually has 来 and 残 despite the other kanji being 旧字体. This might be an error on the source's part, or a compromise for readability. Did you see any other inconsistencies?

Comment: I see at least 桜, 歴, 緑 and 鴎 are shown in 新字体 that are computationally distinct from 旧字体.